# Create a configuration file for React Application for different customers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration

Basically i already have an existing configuration file in my React application for different customers. The issue is, i have too many configurations for different customers. Below is my configuration file.

```
if (process.env.API_ENV && process.env.API_ENV === 'development') {
appConfig = {
    localhost: {
      secret: 'sfsd',
      app_key: 'hfghfgh',
      defaultUser: 'dashboard',
      defaultPassword: '4444',
      shipToMeTab: true,
      searchBar: false,
      tab1: false,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
    },
    'customer1.com': {
      secret: 'sfsd',
      app_key: 'hfghfgh',
      defaultUser: 'dashboard',
      defaultPassword: '4444',
      tab1: false,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,

    },
    'customer2.com': {
      secret: 'sfsd',
      app_key: 'hfghfgh',
      defaultUser: 'dashboard',
      defaultPassword: '4444',
      tab0: true,
      tab1: false,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
    },
    'customer3.com': {
      secret: 'sfsd',
      app_key: 'hfghfgh',
      defaultUser: 'dashboard',
      defaultPassword: '4444',
      tab0: false,
      tab1: false,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
    }
}
```

}

So the configurations for each customer has more parameters and they are different. Currently its maintained in `config.js` file like above.

My question is, Is this the proper way in React to define the configurations for different customers? Are there any other way so that i can define those parameters in a separate file and in terms of optimization as well?

Comment: Are there any inputs on the above query? Thanks